# Developer Option not available on Micromax A101 Superfone with Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, adb

I have Micromax A101 Superfone with Android 4.0.4, I am trying to root it but first of all  I have to enable USB Debugging on it, to do so I need Developer option on my Micromax A101 Superfone with Android 4.0.4 Which is not available. I also tried to enable it by tapping Build Number 7 times but nothing happen. Any help would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: No  didn't. sold my phone.

Comment: Got solution using this app we can see developer options https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.selfip.unet.developer_options&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

To unlock developer mode of your phone  Goto Settings > About > Tap on Build Number multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Bro, it is not shown in settings. But when USB Debugging will be needed by some app like, HELIUM BACKUP, app will redirect you to the Developer option .......

Answer (score 0):

For rooting u have to enable USB Debugging.
Setting -> Developer Option -> USB Debugging

But you cannot enable USB Debugging in A101 even after tapping the Build number 7 times.

For this install an USB Debugging app from Google Play Store from this link : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.tennkia.apr

Then download RootGenius.exe from : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B17jChDV4MyZTjl6ZUJUdHZtUEE/view?usp=sharing

Follow these steps : 
1. Open USB debugging in your phone
2. Enable USB debugging
3. Open Root Genius in PC
4. Connect your phone with PC
5. Click on root button in Root Genius
6. Hold on for few minutes until your device gets rooted and the Root genius gives you the confirmation message!!
7.After rooting process is done, you will find kinguser app is installed in you A101 device which will acts as Super User to give root permission .

You can further cross-check that the device is rooted or not from any root-checker app available on the play store.